# Drag event is firing for seconds

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, electron

I am using Electron and Angular 10 with a registered `HostListener` for the drag-and-drop events. If I circle a dragged file with the mouse over my app and eventually drop it, it takes several seconds until the `drop` event is finally triggered.

Before it triggers hundreds of `dropenter` and `dropleave` events. Can anyone explain that behaviour?

```js
  //Dragover listener
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  public onDragOver(evt) {
    console.log('dragover', new Date().getSeconds());
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
    
  //Dragleave listener
  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event'])
  public onDragLeave(evt) {
    console.log('dragleave', new Date().getSeconds());
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
    
  //Drop listener
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  public ondrop(evt) {
    console.log('drop', new Date().getSeconds());
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
```

The log looks like this:

```
dragleave 23
dragover 23
dragleave 23
dragover 23 <- file dropped around seconds 23
dragleave 23
dragover 23
...
dragleave 25
dragover 25
dragleave 26
dragover 26
drop 26 <-- it took 3 seconds to finally drop the file
```